# Java severity level implementation

Tags: java, oop

I have items in a list which can have a severity level ( those levels are: info,warning,error,delay,...)

I want to program this in a OOP way so that I can add more severity levels easily if needed.
It's been a while since I have used Java so I'm not sure how to do it the right way.

What I have is:

```
    Public class ListItem
    {
       int sev; 
       String name;
       public ListItem(String name, int s)
       {
          this.name = name; this.sev = s;
       }
       ...
    }
```

A severity should have an integer (like '1') and just a name (like 'information')

I'd like to 'predefine' severities like:

```
public static final int WARNING = 1;
public static final int ERROR = 2;
```

But then, how can I display the name 'WARNING' when '1' is given as severity to list item?
Am I having the best approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an enum instead of constants:

```
enum Level {
   INFO, WARNING, ERROR;
}
```

You can print the `Level` using `toString()`

```
Level level = Level.INFO;
System.out.println(level.toString());
```

prints

```
INFO
```

Changing to `ListItem(String name, Level level)` has the advantage of preventing you from creating a `ListItem` with an `int` value that isn't defined as a valid level.

Comment: By implementing the Comparable Interface you could provide an explicit order.

Comment: Enum's aren't extendable, which would prevent the ability to add new ones without modifying the code

Answer (score 0):

If you use `int`s for your constants, you in effect lose any type information, therefore type safety. That is why it it preferable to use a "typesafe enum", specifically the Java `enum`. Every `enum` member is a full-blown object so you can add any methods to it.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `enum` will be well suited for your need.

**2.** Here the `value of the variable` will be **only one** among the **specified values from the enumerated list**. So you will be **confirmed that only the valid values are 
passed.**

**Eg:**

```
public enum Level{

    WARNING, ERROR;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want to extend the system into the future.  If you mind having to modify the code, `enum`'s are well suited for the task.

However, if you want to add new levels over time by introducing them (without the need to modify the original code), you'd be better off creating an Interface or Class that provides the basic functionality you require.

Obviously, you'll want to implement `Comparable` to make your life easier